# WinForm automatically resize window for new controls but still allow user to adjust the size?

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, autosize

I have a windows form that has a list of controls on one side and a graph on the other. I want a checkbox to hide and show the graph, but to also shrink or grow the form to accommodate it.

I tried using `AutoSize=true` for the form, but then the user can't adjust the size of the form (ie expand or shrink the graph to their screen).

Then I tried

```
    private void toggleCheckBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        theGraph.Visible = toggleCheckBox.Checked;

        // automatically resize the form
        this.AutoSize = true;
        this.AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
        this.OnResize(e);

        // this will force the form back to its original size
        // but without it the user cant adjust the form size
        this.AutoSize = false; 
    }
```

How can I display the graph and resize the form on demand, but not restrict the users from resizing the form themselves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I came up with was to save the size, disable the autosize, and then force the size:

```
    private void toggleCheckBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        theGraph.Visible = toggleCheckBox.Checked;

        // automatically resize the form
        this.AutoSize = true;
        this.AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
        this.OnResize(e);

        var NewSize = new System.Drawing.Size(this.Width, this.Height);

        // this will force the form back to its original size
        // allowing the user to adjust the form 
        this.AutoSize = false; 

        // force the form back to its new size
        this.Size = newSize;
    }
```

***Note:*** For the `AutoSize` to work correctly with anchored controls be sure to set a `MinimumSize` for the control being toggled so that a desired amount will be visible on the form.